# Append a dynamic class to a view having a static class

Tags: ember.js

How to append a dynamic class to a view that already has a static class?

http://jsfiddle.net/MBmUs/4/

Comment: possible duplicate of [In an Ember.js Handlebars template, is there a way to have both static and dynamic class attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807783/in-an-ember-js-handlebars-template-is-there-a-way-to-have-both-static-and-dynam)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We've recently added this functionality to Ember. With a build off master, or after 0.9.6 is released, you can do:

```
<div {{bindAttr class="App.foo:a-bound-class :a-static-class"}}></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats pretty sweet. I was sorely missing this feature.

Comment: How to add more than one class in static-class?

Comment: For anyone else that gets here wanting to add multiple static classes you just have to prepend them with a colon like above, something like: {{bindAttr class="App.foo:a-bound-class :a-static-class :another-static-class"}}

Answer (score 1):

With Ember-CLI, you can just render it directly within the class:

```
{{#each items as |item|}}
    <div class="static-class {{item.class}}">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `HTMLBars` this is what works for me:

```
<div class="{{dynamicAttr}} staticAttr">
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```