# ember dynamically change class name

Tags: ember.js

In my ember application I would like to change button depending on if input change. Below is my code that is working fine but that code has redundancy.Is there better way to do it:

html code:

```
<div {{bind-attr class="isActive:active"}}>
    {{#if isActive}}
        <button class="primary button" {{ action 'saveData' }}>Save</button>
        <button id="btn-cancel-info" class="secondary button">Cancel</button>
    {{else}}
        <button class="primary button inactive">Save</button>
        <button id="btn-cancel-info" class="secondary button">Cancel</button>
     {{/if}}
</div>
```

I am setting the value for isActive in objectController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `bind-attr` helper.

```
{{bind-attr class="isNotActive:inactive :primary :button"}}
```

As you can see I added in your other Static classes as well, Below is a link to another question that is about static classes on the `bind-attr` helper.

[Append a dynamic class to a view having a static class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506206/append-a-dynamic-class-to-a-view-having-a-static-class)

Comment: your answer is almost right.You can also specify a class name to add when the property is false:                                      **{{bind-attr class="isNotActive:active:inactive :primary :button"}}**      this way if the property get false the default class will be inactive

Comment: hasib32, that doesn't seem very idiomatic to me, if isNotActive show active class else show inactive (probably you just have them mixed up)